# Sonar does not remove messages from fixed problems, but adds new ones

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

After Sonar working fine for about two years I now face a strange phenomenon (without knowingly having changed anything in configuration).

When I fix a problem reported by Sonar and run it again, the message for this problem is still shown in the dashboard, and when I drill down to the class and the code responsible, the former version of the code without the fix is shown.

So far I thought that Sonar for some reason did not run or could not update its result; until I realized, that new problems are still added to the list! And there they remain even when fixed.

What can be the reason for this strange behaviour? And how can I fix this?

Sonar in version 3.7.2 is used via Jenkins 1.5.1 plugin, and the project is a Maven multi module project.

Comment: Can you try changing a line of code so that one problem is replaced by another? Are both violations shown? Which line of code is shown, the original or changed?

Comment: I cannot see a clear pattern in what is added and what is deleted. It seems that messages of at least the same severity replace the former message, and the new code is shown. My guess is that we have a problem with the sonar data base; but I have no idea how to cope with that.

Comment: Maybe post something on the Sonarqube mailing-list. They are normally pretty helpful over there - http://www.sonarqube.org/resources/join-our-community/

Comment: Thanks, I will probably do that.